# How to deal with the time frame on Tager metamorphosis?

Tags: cthulhutech

The CthulhuTech book Ancient Enemies includes new rules for Tagers, allowing them to metamorphise into a more powerful form of their symbiont. To do this you have to live up to a number of requirements that come in roughly three categories: roleplaying, "Perform action X Y number of times" and spending a lot of time in your Tager form (at least 180 days), during which you have to do certain things as well. Once they manage to pull this off they turn into a cocoon for about a month, after which they are reborn in their new form.

The roleplaying thing is just that: a matter of roleplaying. Although certain forms require some possibly troubling things, including torture, executing prisoners, going in loud when being quite is the more intelligent course of action and other such things, this can theoretically be pulled off. The second one is just a matter of keeping score (though IMO some of these things require you to do these things quite a number of times), so that's not an issue either.

Where I am struggling with as a Storyguide is the last one. A Tager has to spend at least several hours for 180 days out in the world in their Tager form. If you miss even one day the count goes back to zero, unless it was physically impossible AND you spend at least 1 hour in your Tager form that day. While I can write around this last limit, the 180 total days is an issue. Should I allow players to start with an X amount of days on the clock? How about that they've already done this and just have to rack up the points required to metamorphise?

Furthermore, some of them (like the Nightmare) require the Tager to spend a good deal of time (a third out of the 180 days) hunting and killing targets. Should I combine this with gameplay (make it a one-on-one battle, maybe grant XP), should I simply handwave it ("Yeah you find and kill a target. So the next day...") or make an abstract roll for this (1d10 to see if you find a fitting target)? Or should I allow these kills to have already been made?

Comment: @Sardathrion I was thinking about that, but this is something that must become part of the daily routine of a character instead of something that is done on-and-off like many off-time actions.

Comment: Is it worthwhile for an organization to facilitate this transformation in exchange for continued service? (That is, for example, it it worth an agency's time and effort to build then stock with condemned criminals hunting grounds for its looking-to-transform nightmare tragers to sort of game the transformation parameters?)

Comment: @HeyICanChan The organization that the Tagers are part of, the Eldritch Society, are a shadowy bunch dedicated to defending earth from cult activity and rooting it out wherever it may fester. Becoming a Tager requires a LOT from a person, and only the kind of person who would stick with the Society for life would become Tagers. The Society will give the Tagers the room to hunt if they wish, but they would not provide criminals, cultists or even worse, Dhohanoids (who are pretty much evil Tagers) because it goes against the spirit of the Society and is very dangerous because of secrecy issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This largely depends upon why you're playing the game. Do you focus on the fancy bells & whistles that the players can use in the shadow war or are you looking at the sacrifices that the players have to make to prevent the world from plunging over the edge?

- Bells and whistles: excellent moment to do a timejump in which everything is sorted out. This doesn't mean that the player gets it for free! Make him spell it out how he did it (excellent material for future problems or incidents that need to be solved). Let him have it if it looks reasonable, otherwise send him back to the drawing board.
- Sacrifice: this requires playtime! This isn't a walk in the park, triggering metamorphosis requires commitment (as written on p30)

  > A Tager has to listen to the call of his symbiont, giving in to its urges more and more, if one wants to metamorphose.

  If the player is going for this, then the character commitment (why does he want to become suffering personified?) should be there. The hard will be to keep this balanced with the other players. Ideally this is a gradual shift of the character becoming more cold blooded and deadly.

  How do his colleagues react to this shift? He can ask them to go out with him, how do they react when he stalks & kills a Dhohanoids the first time, the second, the third... Do they keep helping him (by assisting in his hunts) or do they try to stop him from killing people or even going out to hunt? Perhaps he goes for the biggest threat when in battle, endangering the team in the process. What is the fallout of this? How do they feel about him when he starts to take revenge on enemies?

  All the requirements give numbers to be reached, but also provide excellent springboards for activities or actions for the player.